# For “I can play the piano a little”, do you use ちょっと or 少し?

Tags: word-choice

> 少しピアノが弾くことができます

Or should I use ちょっと?

I’m mainly interested into “feeling” any difference between these two.

By the way, I also saw “弾ける” being used, which might sound less wooden but I haven’t hit this yet in my grammar textbook - so I use 弾くことができます

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6466/what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%81%a1%e3%82%87%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a8-and-%e5%b0%91%e3%81%97 though I think the comment on the question in that post summarises it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is essentially the same but I would say that 少し has a slightly more formal feel to it. ちょっと is a little more casual and more appropriate for spoken conversation as opposed to written - It is by no means impolite to use the word ちょっと though. When chatting with friends I would use ちょっと, when submitting a written self-introduction for a job or something I would use 少し.